# magento $this->_getProduct()->getStockItem() returns null after rewrite

Tags: magento, model, stock

So i want to rewrite CatalogInventory. I rewrote 2 models with the following code in my config.xml.

```
<models>
        <cataloginventory>
            <rewrite>
                <stock_item>Showoff_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
                <observer>Showoff_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer</observer>
            </rewrite>
        </cataloginventory>
    </models>
```

Now even if these new models are empty, it won't generate the function getStockItem() anymore.. It always returns NULL. In stock, out stock, 10 in stock 0 in stock etc..

**edit:**
Here a screenshot of my module file tree:
[image: File tree]

My (empty) models:

*Observer.php*

```
class Showoff_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer
{

}
```

*Stock/Item.php*

```
class Showoff_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item
{

}
```

How come? please someone could help me with a kick in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also extend the rewritten class

```
class Showoff_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item {

}
```

You should extend the rewritten observer as well.

Comment: Thanks, but i did that. Sorry for not mentioning.
  
`class Showoff_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`

You use mage_catalog instead of mage_cataloginventory?

Comment: can you share your directory structure ? how u have made it. The process is correct and it should work until unless you have not made anything wrong

Comment: A screenshot can be seen here.
http://prntscr.com/7ps1eu

And offcourse in etc/modules/ i got the correct file..

Comment: The funny thing, even when my model or observer is empty it fails and returns NULL.. When i remove the observer in `config.xml` it works again..
Weird!!

Comment: can u paste the content of your observer ? any way are u extending rewritten observer ? also does the event present in your new observer ? enable log and check what error you are getting ?

Comment: Added it to the top post.  
But i want to extend the observer because i need to let people `order out of stock` products without problems or special steps..  
Log was empty, will check it again

Comment: Please extend rewritten observer

Comment: why you need observer to place order for out of stock item. You can enable backorder in magento admin for it.

Comment: That is true.. Only i want to do it a little different.
When only backorder activated in the backend i don't get the result i want.

ANd god damn.. Am i seriously that stupid to not extend the observer -.-
Hmpff.. I thank you a bunch rajatsaurastri..

Could you comment the extend the observer as an answer? That way i can except it..